# How to change a shulker box's texture based on its name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-optifine

So, I have been trying for a bit to find a way to change a brown Shulker Box's texture when its name is "Emergency Cookie Rations". This sounds silly I know, but every technique I have tried has failed: sea of Shulkers may have worked in its own version, but when I tried in mine it failed. My item texture name technique failed, and I tried a technique that worked on pillagers, that also failed.

This is in java 1.16.5 with Optifine.

Comment: Are you using any other mods? That may have impacted the function of sea of shulkers.

Comment: Just optifine, and its required to actually have sea of shulker work.

Comment: Well it seems nobody gets the reputation.
Well unless someone answers within 23 hours. Once that expires its lost to us all.

Comment: Rest in peace reputation

Comment: Use a dye. Its not that hard.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by changing its texture? Because you can't live-update an item's texture without replacing the item with a different one, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a vanilla (blank) resource pack and modify the "`blockentity`" folder. Within this folder, create a new folder with the name of your shulker box (in this case `"Emergency Cookie Rations"`), and add a "`blockstate`" file to it. In this file, specify the model path for each variant of your shulker box, and reference a "model" file for each variant. In each "model" file, specify the texture path for the corresponding color, and reference a "texture" file. Finally, in each "texture" file, specify the RGB *(Red, Green, Blue)* color values for the shulker box. With this setup, you can change the color of any shulker box by changing its name to match the name of one of your variants.